# How to edit or add names after assigning

Tags: r

Suppose my code is this

```
ranks <- 1:3
names(ranks) <- c("one","two","three")
```

Running 'ranks', Output will be like this

```
  one two three
  1   2   3
```

Now I am able to change values 1, 2, 3. But I am unable to change or add - one or two or three. Why? and how to replace them? for suppose replace 'three' with 'third'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing `c` in `names` i.e. `names(ranks) <- c("one","two","three")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the names vector

```
> names(ranks)[3] <- "third"
> ranks
  one   two third 
    1     2     3
```